# Capistrano rollback - what happens to GIT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, capistrano

I have a Rails app that is using GIT, Github, and Capistrano.

I have GIT repositories on my local iMac, Github and the production server.

My normal process is:

I run (1) `$ git push` (to push the code to Github) and then (2) `$ cap deploy` to move the code from Github to the production server.

BTW - I don't use Cap to (3) start my server - I use an SSH terminal.

If I push a lemon and need to restart the production server quickly, I assume the best way would be to use `$ cap deploy:rollback:code`

My questions are:

What happens to the Git repository on the production server?  Does anything there change with the rollback?

Lets say I fix the lemon issue, do I resume my normal process?  Or do I need to do something before I start using the normal process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capistrano keeps a list of previous releases in the `releases` directory. When you rollback, it just changes the `current` symlink. None of this affects your git repo.  To deploy again, just do a normal deploy and it will do the right thing.